# php security to prevent malware insertion

Tags: php, html, security

I am writing a program to be run on a server that takes input from clients in the form http://mywebsite.com/program.php?input=42

I'm concerned that having the client be able to give any value in place of the 42 above could be a security risk because they could put code there that might run on my server. I would like to know if checking that this input is only alphanumberic before proceeding to do anything with it is sufficient protection. If not what should I do to be secure, if so, are there any safety concerns regarding the way in which I do this checking (for example, while checking that the input is alphanumberic could the input if it is malicious code some how get run?)

Thanks

Comment: One way would be to use prepared statements as much as possible

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: also there will need to be user names and passwords, i don't want to restrict that too much

Comment: Long story short, wherever you expect use input you need to always check that input if it's something reasonable and expected. Here for example if you expect a number between 1 and e.g. 10000 you need to always check that that's what you're getting before doing anything with it.

Comment: say i ask for a user name, if i check that its alphanumberic will i be safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s all about how you’re interpreting and using that `$_GET['input']`

If you do such a code:

```
exec($_GET['input']);
```

or

```
if($_GET['input']) == 66) {
     exec("rm -r /");
}
```

That’s obvious that people can do something dangerous.
But it’s less critical than what you think.

The problem of php it’s that its type system **doesn’t encourage people checking their input before using it**.

An usual example is the SQL injectable code:

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '. $_GET['id'].'");
```

Which is really unsafe.

In your example, if your input should be an integer you can check if that’s an integer:

```
if (!is_integer($_GET['input'])) die("invalid");
```

Comment: if my input is a username and i check that its alphanumberic is that enough or should i also check other properties of the input

Comment: i intend only to store usernames in a textfile

Comment: That string is just a data, it will be stored in the file no matter what, so your safety problem doesn’t exist (unless having “banana1234” as username is a safety problem for your program). You will just store that string in the file. Such safety problems might come if your string can be interpreted as a **task** that your server should do.